# Error connecting to SQL Server with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server

I want to connect to SQL Server with Windows authentication and create a SQL Server user.

The error I get while doing this is:

> Login failed for user 'PCNAME\UserName'. Reason: The account is disabled. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18470)

I also get the following error when I try to connect with PsTools:

> Unable to connect: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
> Reason: The account is disabled.

What kind of process should I provide to activate the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user? Or how can I act?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Sounds like you need to reinstall SQL Server

Comment: I hope I don't have to do that.
I'm trying to solve by without  reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are trying to connect while logged on as `pcname\username`. If this user is not created as a Windows user in SQL Server or is disabled in SQL Server, then you will not be able to connect. What you need to do is use an authorized account to created the windows authenticated user in `pcname\username` in SQL Server then you will be able to connect.

As for `pcname\SYSTEM`, this is a built in SID that is used by services. There is no reason you could not add this as a Windows authenticated user in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for quickly answering.

I have a single user and a single computer.
I can't create a user because I can't login with Windows Authentication

Comment: You mean you have lost access to SQLserver? You have no way to connect to it?

Comment: Yes I have. I don't know, I can't access

Comment: Are you able to use SQL Server Management Studio to access your server?

Comment: I can't access with Sql Server Management Studio

[url=https://www.hizliresim.com/qgwc4ua][img]https://i.hizliresim.com/qgwc4ua.jpg[/img][/url]

Comment: By the way, I didn't install SqlServer. Installed with the app I'm using.

Comment: Do you have admin access to your PC?

Comment: Yes, I have admin access

Comment: Ok, then login as admin and use SQL server management studio.

Comment: The user where it says Login failed for user ***** is the admin user

Comment: You then have to reset the password: https://www.sqlshack.com/recover-lost-sa-password/

Comment: Thank you, I will test

Comment: Unfortunately failed. 
I see the same result as I see on the ssms screen, on the cmd screen.

Comment: You need to search for methods to recover lost SQLServer passwords. This is done by starting the service in single user.